# updating master page image from content page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Have made several attempts to update an image in a master page div when switching between content pages. I first tried creating a master page property that I could update from the content page's Page Load event by declaring "MasterType VirtualPath=", but since the master is already loaded by this time it wasn't going to work. It did work when I set the ImageUrl in the master page's page load event (if !Page.IsPostBack then set the image's url attrib), so I know it can work, but I need the image to change for every content page I visit.

Then I tried using the master's menu button click events to set the ImageUrl before loading the content page but this also had no effect. I saw a thread suggesting the use of an UpdatePanel to hold the image, so I may try that next. What's the best way to do this..??

I wouldn't be surprised if a better way is to have the image in a content div instead, and updating that from the master. Any suggestions or links would be most welcome. I can post code if anyone would like to have a look. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you found it difficult. There are many ways to do this but I'll only show one. I just tested this and it worked. How?

In your master page, define your image and add `runat="server"`

```
<img src="put your default image.jpg" runat="server" id="changingImage" />
```

In your content pages, do this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlImage img = Master.FindControl("changingImage") as HtmlImage;

    img.Src = "~/images/imageForContentPage1.jpg"; //replace this image based on your criteria

}
```

Possible exception is `Null Reference` when the name of the image control specified in `.FindControl` could not be found. Make sure it's exactly as you named it in the Master Page. And to prevent a Null Reference Exception, wrap a check around

```
if(img != null)
{
    img.Src = "~/images/imageForContentPage1.jpg";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had added a "imagefile" property in the master's code behind class that I was setting from the content page load event.Then I set the img.src in the master's page load event, which was where I went wrong. I modified your solution so that the property is still set from the content page, and then I use <%#imagefile%> in the master page to set the img element's "src" attribute. Thanks.

Comment: This is a great answer, but .NET prefer Pattern Matching nowadays like so: [CODE] if (Master.FindControl("changingImg") is HtmlImage img)
            {
                img.Src = "~/Images/changingImg.png";
            }[CODE]